# What is wrong with the settings or the mesh? It doesn't subdivide properly

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface

I created a 2D plane and formed a person. Then I added a solidify modifier to give it volume and then applied a subdivision surface modifier. I tried applying them both but it didn't make a difference. I would be very greatful for help. Thank you already for your time!
[image: here without the subdivision surface modifier]

[image: this is what happens with the subdivision surface modifier]

[image: this is what it lookes like after increasing the crease on the solidify modiefier]

Answer (score 0):

Set the Crease of the solidify modifier;

[image]

Gives you;

[image]

And a lesser value;

[image]

Gives you;

[image]

To get a more smoothly rounded edge, remember to increase the subdivisions;

[image]

Comment: Thank you for looking at it. I tried what you suggested, but there are still new faces that are appearing and "spikes" where the vertices are. Do you know how to fix that too?

Comment: Please update your question with those areas in a screenshot Edit: nevermind, you already did, checking...

Comment: Select all your verts, search for "Merge By Distance", and click on it. See if that helps